# Cannot change material texture with script in WebGL build (but I can in the editor/game) (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, textures, unity-webgl

I'm building a project for WebGL in unity, using universal rendering pipeline.

The scene is simple: just a cube. I assigned an URP/Lit material to the cube, and assigned a default basemap to the texture.

This renders fine in WebGL.

The problem begins when I try to fetch a texture from an URL. I have a text field in the HTML that embeds the player and I use this function to send a message to unity:

```
function loadit() {
    var url=document.getElementById('url').value;
    unityInstance.SendMessage('Cube','LoadTheTexture',url);
}
```

This actually calls the following function in unity:

```
public async Task<Texture>   LoadTheTexture(string url) {
    _texture = await GetRemoteTexture( url );

    _texture.wrapMode=TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
    Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.sharedMaterial.SetTexture("_BaseMap",  _texture);
    return _texture;
}
```

I know that it works because it fetches the texture (GetRemoteTexture is a function that uses UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture, which works.

The console logs

> "[CachedXMLHttpRequest] 'http://xxxxxxx/DSF0374-copy-scaled.jpg' downloaded successfully (743969 bytes) and stored in indexedDB cache".

However, nothing changes.

In the editor/game everything works fine - it fetches and replaces the texture of the material.

But in the WebGL build, nothing changes - the default texture remains.

Any idea what might be the cause?

GetRemoteTexture function:

```html
 public static async Task<Texture> GetRemoteTexture ( string url )
{
    using( UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture( url ) )
    {
        //begin requenst:
        var asyncOp = www.SendWebRequest();

        //await until it's done: 
        while( asyncOp.isDone==false )
        {
            await Task.Delay( 1000/30 );//30 hertz
        }

        //read results:
        if( www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError )
        {
            //log error:
            #if DEBUG
            Debug.Log( $"{ www.error }, URL:{ www.url }" );
            #endif

            //nothing to return on error:
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            //return valid results:
            return DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent( www );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes when dealing with caching, it's a good idea to have an UNID-hash after the url to signal that something has actually changed with the file. Eg. `...copy-scaled.jpg?2222222222` then the new file `...copy-scaled.jpg?111111111`. Can't remember the exact terms for this, but maybe you can find something using this approach. 

Also, what happens if you instead do `SetTexture("_BaseMap", null);` ? Is it removing the current texture? If not, you have to look up how to modify active textures that are being used.

Comment: [Accessing and Modifying Material parameters via script - Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MaterialsAccessingViaScript.html?_ga=2.195571948.1514818523.1591351298-1544563512.1591351298)

Comment: I don't think caching is the issue because when I try a new file name, nothing changes. I'll try to set the texture to null and let you know - however it will take some time, it takes ages to compile the webgl build -even for just a simple cube.

Comment: Okay, yeah, trying a new filename should not cause any problems with caching. I'll look around some more and see what I can find in the meantime.

Comment: Can you please post the `GetRemoteTexture` function?

Comment: of course, I added it to the end of the question. (still building. webgl build times are killing me.)

Comment: The build is done, and null doesn't work either. There's probably a difference between how the editor/game player handles active textures and how WebGL does it. But I cannot find any information about it. Maybe it's a bug? If it didn't work in the editor, I would be sure that I'm doing something wrong but this... I'm at a loss :)

Comment: By the way, I previously tried to change the texture using rend.material.SetTexture, and rend.material.MainTexture which also didn't do anything.

Comment: Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLOru6QQShM) and this [post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/swapping-texture-via-script.3124/)

Comment: I checked both. The video is actually almost doing what I'm doing, and of course it works (it works for me in the editor too).
I'm not sure the manager approach in the post is suitable for me, since I'm fetching an arbitrary texture from an URL source so no possibility to include the texture with the build. however my material is already assigned to the gameobject, so it's in the build (and I can see it with the default texture).
I think the right question here is "what's different in how materials are handled in the script in the editor and in webgl?")

Comment: Maybe add url = Pointer_stringify(url); in loadit function?